# How do I set spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, environment-variables

I have looked through similar questions that have been asked before. No luck so far. I'm using PySpark within a venv environment. How do I go about changing the setting? Do I do it from within jupyter notebook/python script? Or do I need to use bash command? Is it in a specific configuration file? If so, where is it located?

Comment: You can add configuration options when initiating the SparkSession. like ```SparkSession.builder\
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.2.1") \
    .config("spark.jars.repositories", "https://maven-central.storage-download.googleapis.com/maven2/")\
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
    .getOrCreate()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This config, along many others, has been moved to: SQLConf - sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala

This can be set either in the config file or via command line in spark, using:

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", 1000)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

You can set it up in your `.config` file or you can use the command line

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", <value>)
```